# Merge arguments with a file side by side

Tags: text-processing

This is the prefix saved in a file

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat prefix.txt 
A. 
B. 
C. 
wolf@linux:~$
```

I would like to merge this with another input (in verfical format)

This is the sample input `AB_CD_EF`, however it's in a horizontal format.

So I used `tr` to change it to vertical format.

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo AB_CD_EF | tr _ '\n'
AB
CD
EF
wolf@linux:~$
```

How do I merge these 2 output to produce:

```
A. AB
B. CD
C. EF
```

I've been thinking to use `paste`, but it doesn't work with stdin.

```
wolf@linux:~$ paste $(echo AB_CD_EF | tr _ '\n') prefix.txt
paste: AB: No such file or directory
wolf@linux:~$
```

This data is not in sequence, I'm not looking for solution such as `echo {A..C}`

If there's better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: `paste prefix.txt <(echo AB_CD_EF | tr _ '\n')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`paste` does work with standard input, but you need to tell it where (with a `-` argument), and provide input on standard input:

```
echo AB_CD_EF | tr _ '\n' | paste -d\  prefix.txt -
```

In your attempt, the text you wish to paste is provided as arguments, not on standard input; `paste` expects file names there.